# From Where Default Blocks are rendering in my local module

Tags: magento

I am trying to learn Magento. Creating a custom HelloBlock module i want to grasp the template behavior of Magento. So below is the `helloblock.xml` file which i placed under

```
app > design > frontend > default > default > layout directory
```

What is unclear to me that in my helloblock.xml file i did not ask Magento to load header, footer and sidebars. So from where my module is inheriting those blocks.

Thanks alot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <helloblock_index_index>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="core/template" name="helloblock" template="helloblock/view.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </helloblock_index_index>
    <helloblock_index_mymethod>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="helloblock" template="helloblock/view.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </helloblock_index_mymethod>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined new handles (helloblock_index_index, helloblock_index_mymethod) corresponding to your new controller actions (and related pages).

You need to know that to each controller action, correspond a list of handles. You can see that list of handles just by adding tha in any template file:

```
<?php var_dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());?>
```

That will show you for example:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'default' (length=7)
  1 => string 'cms_page' (length=8)
  2 => string 'STORE_default' (length=18)
  3 => string 'THEME_frontend_default_default' (length=27)
  4 => string 'cms_index_index' (length=15)
  5 => string 'Homepage' (length=8)
  6 => string 'customer_logged_in' (length=18)
```

You can see that the first handle loaded is `default`.
It's in the file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml that you will find the definition for `default handle` in the xml node . You can see in that definition that a block root and child blocks for header, head, content, etc are defined. This layout is inherited for all the handles you will create. You just have to define the child blocks you want to load and where as you did.